# Galaxy Watch Designer: Generating CSR Fail Error when attempting to generate distribution certificate to test on watch

Tags: csr, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am using Galaxy Watch Designer to make a new watch face for my Galaxy Watch (46mm). I have made the face with no issue and obtained an author certificate. However, when I try to make the distribution certificate to test the face on the watch, I am able to connect to my watch from the program and then it prompts me to sign in with my Samsung Account. After that, it throws the error "**Generating CSR Fail**". I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.

**I have tried:**

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the program
- Using my laptop and a different network to try to connect to the watch.
- Reinstalling the program to the desktop as opposed to the Program Files directory.

.

I haven't tried messing with a different `java version` as I didn't feel it was necessary.

Any thoughts?